# IE10 download link fails with cross-domain redirect

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect, http-headers, download

I'm changing the behaviour of a download endpoint to redirect to a different domain from which to actually download the file. This has started failing in IE10 (haven't tried earlier) while it works fine in Chrome et. al. Rather than bring up the download dialog it redirects the user to the new file url and then brings up the dialog.

Here's the new sequence of requests and their headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 307 Temporary Redirect
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 11:30:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 307 Temporary Redirect
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Date: 1380713407016
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private
Location: https://someotherdomain.com/files/100?token=jfkldsfdshlfsdlkdfs
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Robots-Tag: none
X-Runtime: 0.129865
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1

curl -I "https://someotherdomain.com/files/100?token=jfkldsfdshlfsdlkdfs"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Wed, 02 Oct 2013 11:19:43 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 9961
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="some file "with" + & wierd characters.jpeg"; filename*=UTF-8''some%20file%20%22with%22%20%2B%20%26%20wierd%20characters.jpeg
Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Sep 2013 15:30:53 GMT
ETag: "04e88973d658dc21e263865cbd6d20da"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Download-Options: noopen
Cache-Control: max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
```

Can anyone see anything suspect. I'm led to believe that the Content-Type and Content-Disposition are the important headers and they're OK so it must be the redirect / new domain that causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. The original domain was in the corporate security policy under the Intranet tab it Internet Options and the second wasn't.